# Redirect to google map with auto start?

Tags: php, html

is there a way to redirect a user to Google Map without asking to start? it should start automatically

Right now I just redirecting the user to

https://www.google.it/maps?q=32+FOGERTY+STREET++BRAMPTON++ON++L6Y5K2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jrLc.jpg

What I was trying to do is click start automatically

Comment: I could use some more information, what are you trying to do? Is this a mobile application? Is 'Start automatically' start with the directions automatically?

Comment: it is a web application. html5 + php. I wanted it to start the route automatically

Answer (score 1):

Okay, based on what I -think- you're trying to do, try this:
`http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=32%20Fogerty%20Street%20Brampton%20L6Y5K2&nav=1`
Found it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9j2ki4/google_maps_autostart_navigating/)!

Comment: There's a problem though, this works on Android but not on IOS